# How to convert surface shader to Vertex/Fragment code in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm wondering how I can convert this surface shader code to Vertex/Fragment pragma:

```
Shader "Custom/Diamond Opaque Test" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _SpecColor ("Specular Color", Color) = (0.5,0.5,0.5,1)
        _Shininess ("Shininess", Range (0.01, 1)) = 0.078125
        _RimPower ("Rim Power", Range(0,8.0)) = 3.0
        _ReflectColor ("Reflection Color", Color) = (1,1,1,0.5)
        [NoScaleOffset] _Cube ("Cubemap", CUBE) = "" {}
    }

    SubShader {

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf BlinnPhong

        struct Input {
            float3 worldRefl;
            float3 viewDir;
        };

        samplerCUBE _Cube;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed4 _ReflectColor;
        half _Shininess;
        half _RimPower;

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            o.Albedo = _Color.rgb;
            o.Gloss = _Color.a;
            o.Specular = _Shininess;
            half rim = saturate(dot (normalize(IN.viewDir), o.Normal));
            o.Emission = texCUBE (_Cube, IN.worldRefl).rgb * _ReflectColor.rgb * pow(rim,_RimPower);;
        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    FallBack "Mobile/Diffuse"
}
```

The shader code above is the red gem on the left of the picture below:

[image: no shadow]

My goal is to look similar to the gem on the right. I have a couple of challenges along the way. The gem on the left is opaque and accepts shadows. The gem on the right has front face transparency but not the back. This however does not accept shadows. I had to make the gem on the let BlinnPhong so it can cast and receive shadows.

[image: shadow]

Is it possible to create different controls for the front and back face transparency? Also is there a way for transparent objects to accept shadows? I wanted to add outlines to the gem so it can be seen farther away. Is there a way to add outlines within the same Pass or does it have to have its own separate Pass? Also, how can you darken the received shadow? Will all these demands tax the hell out of the GPU? The game is for a mobile platform.

I am a complete beginner in CG Programming. My first step is to figure out of the translate surface programming to vertex/fragment. Any examples would be extremely grateful.

I did purchase a couple of gem assets in the asset store, but some of them can cast shadows but can't receive or can't cast or receive at all. What gives? The gem shader on the right is from one of the purchased assets from the asset store. I don't want to share their shader script on this site without their permission.

Comment: I'm confused there is many question In your question? 1-surface to frag 2-Double side transparent

Comment: why do you want convert this shader to fragment shader? It's better to use surface shader because It's easy to edit.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali
1). There are some features I liked in the assets I purchased, but it's written vertex/fragment. I wanted to take some parts of the code and added on mine. I wanted to convert surface to vertex/fragment so I can understand how to manipulate it.

2). I wanted to control the amount of fog that's in the gem by controlling the alpha of the front face and back face. Setting the alpha for the entire gem makes it look more like glass or plastic. For an example I want to set the back face alpha of a white gem closer to solid rather than darker colors. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: writing fragment shader is not easy but if you like to do It you should learn fragment shaders but any way there are fragment shaders for each light modeling [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Smooth_Specular_Highlights)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite an involved process, though i recommend that you start with downloading the unity shader source code from their website. Most of the actual shading is done in UnityStandardBRDF.cginc, UnityPBSLighting.cginc, and UnityStandardCore.cginc. You can also find these files on github if you google them.

Basically, the base structure of a forward-add shader looks like this:

```
Shader "MyForwardAddShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Some texture", 2D) = "white"{}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"RenderType"="Geometry" "Queue" = "Geometry"}

        Pass 
        {
            // Forward Base pass - this applies main directional light and ambient
            Name "FORWARD"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma target 3.5

            #pragma multi_compile_fwdbase
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            // I Like to keep these in separate include files
            #include "MyForwardBase.cginc"

            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            // Forward Add pass - this is added once per extra light source

            Name "FORWARD_DELTA"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardAdd" }
            Blend SrcAlpha One
            Fog { Color (0,0,0,0) } // in additive pass fog should be black
            ZWrite Off
            ZTest LEqual

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma target 3.5

            #pragma multi_compile_fwdadd_fullshadows
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "MyForwardAdd.cginc"

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you'd also need a shadowcaster pass for it to cast shadows (you can just copy the pass used in the standard shader source code), as well as a Meta pass if you want to use baked lighting.

A file like "MyForwardBase.cginc" should include definitions for the vertex input and output structs, as well as the vertex and fragment functions for the pass. With this setup, you also need to define the uniforms (property variables) there. Some variables you might need for the light calculations:

```
// Calculate this in the vertex shader and normalize per fragment
o.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
float3 viewDir = _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - o.worldPos;

// In the ForwardBase pass, _WorldSPaceLightPos0.xyz stores the direction of the main directional light, instead of position. 
// Use this in the vertex function:
half3 mainLightColor = _LightColor0.rgb;
half3 mainLightDir = _WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz;
```

For the ForwardBase pass, you'll need to include "AutoLight.cginc" and use this macro in the vertex function:

```
COMPUTE_LIGHT_COORDS(o);
```

Which in turn requires you to have this macro in the VertexOutput struct:

```
UNITY_LIGHTING_COORDS(6,7) // 6, 7 can be any texture interpolator IDs, they will translate to TEXCOORD6 and TEXCOORD7 in this case
```

ForwardAdd light attenuation works like this:

```
UNITY_LIGHT_ATTENUATION(atten, i, i.worldPos.xyz); // Here, worldPos is stored in the vertex output struct and calculated per vertex
half3 lightColor = _LightColor0.rgb * atten;
```

There are also macros for finding out if the pixel is in shadow, you can find them in AutoLight.cginc. In the ForwardAdd pass, light direction is calculated per-vertex as such:

```
o.lightDir      = _WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz - o.worldPos.xyz * _WorldSpaceLightPos0.w;
```

Personally, i like to create small CGIncludes for each feature, such as reflection, refraction, triplanar mapping, etc. and just include them whenever i need them. I also tend to keep a separate function called "Lighting" in its own include file, since lighting calculations are shared between the passes. This function takes all the variables like lightDir, viewDir, albedo, roughness etc. as arguments and returns the shaded color of the fragment.

Like i said, it's quite an involved process, and this is just a primer. Implementing the lighting function is a story of its own, though looking through UnityStandardBRDF.cginc can help with this. I recommend that you start with a basic blinn-phong model for debugging and improve from there.